# How do I get a value from a complex subquery in Group By?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to group data AND get calculate perctages of the whole.

The grouping works, but I can't get the total Volume. The commented out line does not recognise T.

```
SELECT P.[LiqProvider], P.[Volume], 
-- P.[Volume]/(SELECT SUM([Volume]) FROM T)

FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT A.[LiqProvider] ,COUNT(A.[ExecSignedAmount]) AS Trades, SUM(ABS(A.[ExecSignedAmount])) AS Volume
        FROM (
               SELECT  [LiqProvider],[Symbol],[ExecSignedAmount]
              FROM [BT].[LB].[FilledOrders] 
              WHERE [OrderDate] = '2018-07-02'
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT  [LiqProvider],[Symbol],[ExecSignedAmount]
              FROM [BT].[LB2].[FilledOrders] 
              WHERE [OrderDate] = '2018-06-02'
          ) AS A 
        GROUP BY A.[LiqProvider]
      ) AS T 
  ) AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as you have specified (AS Volume) but your commented out line is trying to find [Volume], if that makes sense i have only recently started using SQL so i am not sure this seems to be something I would check. Let me know if this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer query doesn't know any T table. It knows a P table. Since you want both volume and its sum, you should use OVER:

```
SELECT P.[LiqProvider], P.[Volume], SUM(P.[Volume]) over ()
FROM.....(the rest of your code)
```